# How to get the array index by a perticular condition

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract final_year_project {
    struct hospital_record {
        address patient;
        string hospital;
        string docter;
        uint256 time;
        string disease;
        string pescription;
    }

    mapping(address => hospital_record) public hospital_mapping;
    hospital_record[] public hospital_array;

    function data(
        string memory _hospital,
        string memory _docter,
        string memory _disease,
        string memory _pescription
    ) public {
        uint256 _time;
        _time = block.timestamp;
        hospital_mapping[msg.sender] = hospital_record(
            msg.sender,
            _hospital,
            _docter,
            _time,
            _disease,
            _pescription
        );
        hospital_array.push(
            hospital_record(
                msg.sender,
                _hospital,
                _docter,
                _time,
                _disease,
                _pescription
            )
        );
    }

    function read_records() public view returns (hospital_record[] memory) {
        return hospital_array;
    }
}
```

I want to get the address record (mapping key) by only msg.sender

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since `hospital_mapping` is `public` you don't have to do anything. You can read the value as if there were a function `hospital_mapping(address)` that returns a hospital_record.

For example using ethers.js:

```js
const hospitalForWallet = await contract.hospital_mapping(walletAddress);
console.log(`patient : ${hospitalForWallet.patient});
```